# Syntax of WFS request in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, wfs

I am in need of the correct syntax for loading WFS layer using OpenLayers. I have gone through many examples on the OpenLayers site and other examples, but can't figure out how to use the necessary and optional options like strategies, protocols etc

Comment: Where do you serve your wfs layer? geoserver, arcgis or sth. it all dependens on serving structure...

Comment: please post the code you have tried so far and what is not working for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is somethin like

```
var wfsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector({
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        url: 'http://example.com/wfs',
        featureType: 'myFeatureTypeName',
        featureNS: 'topp',
        geometryName: 'the_geom'
    }),
    strategies: [ new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX() ]
});
```

getting you? Can you see any GetFeature-Request in Firebug or Inspector? Have you set up your OpenLayers.ProxyHost variable?

Comment: thank you Crischan, now i have a wfs layer, i have 1 more question. the layer i am retriving has a sld file attached to it. so that, in same wms layer i get a legend. but in wfs layer i don't get legend/

Comment: I don't think there's a legend control for WFS in OpenLayers. WFS+SLD would be WMS (roughly speaking) and for OpenLayers WFS is purely a vector data source with no knowledge about any styles attached to it by your WFS server software.

Comment: thanks again, i now style the vector layer using openlayers stylemap and use wms layer for legend.