# Load a feature from geoserver using WFS protocol on localhost

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs

I am a student enginner in GIS , I want to load my features from geoserver using WFS protocol. I'm using this code but it's not appearing in my browser

```
    OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";
var map,wfs;


function init() {
//-11593508, 5509847, -11505759, 5557774
    var extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
        474813,  211897, 491713, 227436.5
    );
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
    controls: [
        new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoom(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({'ascending':false}),
    ]
});
  var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                    "test_postgres:territoire", "http://mylocalhost:8080/geoserver/test_postgres/wms",
                    {
                        LAYERS: 'test_postgres:territoire',
                        STYLES: '',
            format: 'image/svg',
                    },
                    {
                        isBaseLayer: true,
                    } 
                );
  var wfsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
        styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
            strokeWidth: 3,
            strokeColor: "#333333"
        }) 
    });


        map.addLayer(wfsLayer);


map.zoomToMaxExtent();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified the required parameters for making a WFS request. see this [Syntax of WFS request in OpenLayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25712/syntax-of-wfs-request-in-openlayers) , the parameters are defined in the protocol.

you will also need to setup a proxy for making WFS request, otherwise you will get cross-domain-allow-origin problem. If you came across this see [How to proxy Geoserver through Apache in Windows](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31750/how-to-proxy-geoserver-through-apache-in-windows)

WFS is always difficult for starters so don't lose your hope soon.

**UPDATE**
My allowed host list

```
allowedHosts = ['www.openlayers.org', 'openlayers.org', 
            'labs.metacarta.com', 'world.freemap.in', 
            'prototype.openmnnd.org', 'geo.openplans.org',
            'sigma.openplans.org', 'demo.opengeo.org',
            'www.openstreetmap.org', 'sample.azavea.com',
            'v2.suite.opengeo.org', 'v-swe.uni-muenster.de:8080', 
            'vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org', 'www.openrouteservice.org',
            '127.0.0.1:8888', '127.0.0.1',
            'localhost:8888', 'localhost'
            ]
```

also check whether the proxy is working or not for this goto

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi
```

in your browser, this should open up the OpenLayers website

Comment: Thank's byom for your reply to my question ! i added the protocole & all required parameters but it is not work